# Storyboard view controllers are black

Tags: ios13, xcode11.1

I have installed a new Xcode version 11.1 in my mac and open my existing project, while i’m trying to open my storyboard its completely shown black UI.

[image: XCode UI]

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, all i did is

clear constraint, for my case the source was from UITableView, and make sure constraints are attached to safeare not superview.

[image]

from toolbar on the top go to Editor > Canvas > Layout Rectangle Very important you have to repeat this step 3 times

Quit XCode and reopen it again , all should be fixed

I've noticed this happen when i switch view for different devices 8, 11, 4s

Good luck